# Replace sequence of dots with one underscore

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a string holding any number of dots, sometimes also a sequence of dots.

I want to replace every `.` (dot) by `_` (underscore) but when there is a sequence of dots, this should also result only in a single underscore.

Any ideas?

I`m using java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `replaceall` method as:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\.+","_");
```

[**See it on Ideone**](http://www.ideone.com/PhK6h)

Explanation of the regex `\\.+`

`.` is a regex metacharacter to match anything (except newline). Since we want to match a literal `.` we escape it with `\`. Since both Java Strings and regex engine use `\` as escape character we need to use `\\`, `+` is the quantifier for one or more.

Alternatively we can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[.]+","_");
```

Since a `.` inside a character class is treated literally there is not need to escape it.

Comment: Nice answer. @Sergiu don't forget that you can (and should) mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Dunaril:I tried accepting it as answered as soon as I got it but I have to wait for 10 minutes until I can set it to accepted and I had to leave the computer.